# Move an object in a threejs scene with mouse

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to move an object in a threejs scene, but i can't select one object when i click with mouse. I tried adapt this code
(https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html) for my application, but it didn't work in my case.

This function was correct?

The camera position and rotate is correct (see complete code)?

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    console.log("function onDocumentMouseDown");
    console.log(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objetos );

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        alert("finalmente");
        console.log(intersects[0]);
        intersects[0].object.material.transparent = true;
        intersects[0].object.material.opacity = 0.1;
        SELECTED = intersects[0].object;
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane );
        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
             offset.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point ).sub(plane.position);
        }
    }
}
```

For complete code access https://github.com/lohmanndouglas/Simulador.git

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't select "one object"? Can you select all of the other objects and you are not able to select *only* that one?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have many objects in scene and i need to drag one of this objects with the mouse (like the example draggablecubes), but in my application i have other code structure, so this example is not work in my project. I was thinking that error is in the camera position/rotation. Thanks in advance for your help :).

Comment: Your page [is not working](https://rawgit.com/lohmanndouglas/Simulador/master/simulador.html). Can you not make a fiddle to show your code?

Comment: This [link](http://rawgit.com/lohmanndouglas/Simulador/master/simulador.html) works . You click in yellow torus and add a torus into a scene, that is ok. Now I need drag the red torus in scene. I am trying to implement the function to do this in file simulador/view/Cena3D.js, where I implement the function onDocumentMouseDown(event). In this function I click in the red torus and the torus has change the opacity, but the code didn't work I can not able to intersect objects. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused because I am using others DIV in my page, so to correct this problem its necessary to convert clientX and clientY to the relative coordinate of the DIV.

I changed the lines where I update the variables mouse.x and mouse.y.

```
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

For this:

```
   mouse.x = ( (event.clientX - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left) /event.currentTarget.width ) * 2 - 1;
   mouse.y = - ( (event.clientY - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top) / event.currentTarget.height ) * 2 + 1;
```

This works for me